# how to select a specific row in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a table of users and the last column of each row has a delete button which delete the corresponding user. I have this code which deletes the user through AJAX and then hide the row.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id=$('#pass_id');
    var temp_id=id.val();

    $('#deletebutton').click(function(){

        var ok=confirm("You really want to delete this property?");

        if(ok)
        {   
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "index-valid.php",
                data: prop_id=id,
                success: function(data) {

                    $('#deletebutton').closest('tr').hide();
                    alert("Successfully deleted.");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

But the code doesn't delete my row; it only hides the row, and only works on the first row.

Comment: Change your `deletebutton` ID to a class.

Comment: You're using an id on a deletebutton that appears more than once in the html. You should switch to using a class first, see what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have more than one button with the same ID. Use a class instead then this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id=$('#pass_id');
    var temp_id=id.val();

    $('.deletebutton').click(function(){
    var button = $(this);
    var ok=confirm("You really want to delete this property?");

    if(ok)
    {   
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "index-valid.php",
                data: prop_id=id,
                success: function(data) {
                    button.closest('tr').remove();
                    alert("Successfully deleted.");
                }
            });
    }
});
```

});

This will delete the row from the page completed.

Comment: @user628961 You're right, updated it to work properly now by saving the reference to the button to a variable and calling closest('tr').remove(); on that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `hide()`, replace it by  `remove()`.

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple delete buttons with the same ID!

Answer (score 0):

U should try to change ID to CLASS

```
$('.deletebutton').each(function(){

    $(this).click(function(){


    var ok=confirm("You really want to delete this property?");

    if(ok)
    {   
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "index-valid.php",
                    data: prop_id=id,
                    success: function(data) {

                    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                    alert("Successfully deleted.");



                    }
                });
    }





    });

});
```

Comment: No need to use the each loop, can bind straight from the $('.deletebutton') selector. Also, will the $(this) inside the success function still refer to the button?

Comment: yeap, $(this) still refer to button. :)